# CSS bubble cloud

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, bubble-chart

I'm trying to generate a bubble cloud / bubble chart looking similar to this, but without animations:
https://codepen.io/seogi1004/pen/WaWZOz

The bubbles should be kind of centered without overlapping to minimize the space between them.

This is my current progress:
https://codepen.io/FelixRe/pen/PobjNyM

```
#css
   .circle{
      border-radius: 50px; 
      border: 1px solid black;
      margin: 1px;
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;
    }
    
    .container{
      display: flex; 
      flex-wrap: wrap;
      width: 500px;
    }
    
    #app{
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
    }
    .active{
      background-color: red;
    }

#html
<div id="app">
<div class="container">
    <span
      v-for="i in 20"
      :key="i"
      :style="size()"
      class="circle"
    >
      <span class="body-1">{{ i }}</span>
    </span>
  </div>
</div>

#script
const app = Vue.createApp({
  methods: {
      random(min, max) {
        return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min)
      },
      size() {
        const size = this.random(80, 100)
        return 'width: ' + size + 'px; height: ' + size + 'px;'
      },
    },
})

app.mount('#app')
```

Do you think there is a lean way without hardcoding absolute positions?

Comment: Why not using the library itself ? It's just the animation that bothers you ? https://github.com/juijs/vue-graph Otherwise, you need to go full in an learn how to use D3.js I guess: https://levelup.gitconnected.com/d3-js-and-vue-js-7a6a721eb79f

Comment: This is a great use case for Poisson Disc Sampling. There are many great articles on it I am sure you can find.

Comment: @kissu besides the unnecessary animation, I want the bubbles to behave like a multi select and customize them more than what is possible with the library. I thought about using d3 but think it might be overkill.

Comment: @TomBonynge thanks for the hint. I'll check that out.

Comment: What kind of customization ? If it's a little bit complex, D3 will probably not be overkill. This may be a good starting point: https://vallandingham.me/bubble_charts_with_d3v4.html